# C++でオーバーロードしたoperator=が正しく動作しない

Tags: c++

C++で明示的にコピーコンストラクタ・代入演算子を実装したいのですが、
代入が出来なくて悩んでいます。
コンパイル自体は通ります。

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;

    A() : x(0) {}
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    A(const A& other) : A(other.x) {}
    A& operator=(const A& rhs)
    {
        return *this; //良く見かける書き方
        //return A(rhs); // 試したけど駄目
        //return *(new A(rhs)); // 試したけど駄目
    }
};

A _g = A(30);
int main()
{
    A a(10);
    A b(20);
    A c = a;    // OK
    b = a;      // Not Assigned
    _g = a;     // Not Assigned

}
```

環境：
　IDE：**Visual Studio 2019**
　C++言語標準：**ISO C++17 標準**

Comment: 例えばこの記事 [割り当て](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/assignment?view=vs-2019) だと、いったんローカルな変数に代入してから`return *this;`しているようですが、記事と同様のコーディングを試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: メンバ変数への代入をされていないのは意図したものですか？だとしたら何も起こりません。そうでないならメンバ変数についても代入処理を書く必要があります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やりたいことって

```
A& operator=(const A& rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    return *this;
}
```

ですよね？
代入した際のメンバ変数に対する処理も記述しないと何もされません。
Visual Studio 2019　を使用されているのであればデバッガでステップ実行して、b=aの行でステップインして動作を追ってみると、何が起こっているか見ることができます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。デバッガでステップしていくとコピーコンストラクタを通過していたのでメンバがコピーされたものだと思ってました。